# Get rid duplicated rows by a column with set inside

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, set

Giving this Data sample, I would like to deduplicate rows that contains identical `set`, this is easy with simple data but

with this example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME':['foo foo','foo foo fighter','bar','bar bar'],'SET_NAME':[{'foo'},{'foo','fighter'},{'bar'},{'bar'}]})
```

Output[1]:

```
    NAME            SET_NAME
0   foo foo         {foo}
1   foo foo fighter {foo, fighter}
2   bar             {bar}
3   bar bar         {bar}
```

by using something like `df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['SET_NAME'])` ( unhashable type: 'set' error) I expect to get this:

Output[2]:

```
    NAME            SET_NAME
0   foo foo         {foo}
1   foo foo fighter {foo, fighter}
2   bar             {bar}
```

Note that row 2 and 3 were deduplicated because it has the same content in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the dtype to `str` and then call [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated) and invert the mask using `~`:

```
In[131]:
df1.loc[~df1['SET_NAME'].astype(str).duplicated()]

Out[131]: 
              NAME        SET_NAME
0          foo foo           {foo}
1  foo foo fighter  {fighter, foo}
2              bar           {bar}
```

Then it will be able to find the duplicates. Note that I strongly advise storing non-scalar values in a `DataFrame` as you lose vectorised operations

Comment: funny! I am not used to change of format, I didnt realised about this solution, Perfect! Futhermore, set('foo foo fighters'.split(' ')) and set('fighters foo foo'.split(' ')) gives an example of how similar sets has the same order, so string comparison is valid to this target.